# Show more information for Xamarin Exceptions in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I have a xamarin project and I use mostly VS 2017 Community for development. Unfortunately does VS not show any useable information in case of a unhandled excetption.
A Window like this appears:

[image]

In the Output is the following logged:

```
InspectorDebugSession(13): HandleTargetEvent: UnhandledException
07-03 09:59:37.391 E/mono    (12270): Unable to find seq points for method '(wrapper managed-to-native) System.Diagnostics.Debugger:Mono_UnhandledException_internal (System.Exception)', offset 0x64.
07-03 09:59:37.391 F/        (12270): * Assertion at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mono/mini/debugger-agent.c:5746, condition `sp' not met
07-03 09:59:37.392 F/libc    (12270): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 12290 (Debugger agent)
Step request failed: Exception of type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException' was thrown.
InspectorDebugSession(13): HandleTargetEvent: TargetExited
```

With the same error on Visual Studio on MacOS i have have the complete message with inner exception etc.

Do I have to configure that in a specific way to get these information on the windows PC aswell?

These are my Xamarin settings:

[image]

EDIT 1 : here are my  output windows settings:

[image]

EDIT 2: Exception Settings
[image]

Comment: Could you show your settings of options - debugging - output window?

Comment: added a screenshot

Comment: change your Exceptions Settings to allow more than default

Comment: `Tools` -> `Projects and Solutions` -> `Build and Run` -> `MSBuild...` -> Both choose `Diagnostic`, in this way, you could find more detailed information.

Comment: @YorkShen unfortunately still the same information on the exception.

Comment: @YuriS I added a screenshot of my exception settings. What could I change here?

Comment: Still cant find useful information in output window?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the output is still the same.

Comment: Really strange is, is that on VS on Mac there is a nice dialog with inner exception and message and everything. And when I remember right it was better in the past..

Comment: Instead of square rectangles make sure by clicking on checkboxes they show check mark

Comment: aaah didn't realize that there are not all options selected. it works better now. I do get the right exception now. thanks! :)